# Has there ever been mention of economic crisis in Marvel comics?

Tags: marvel

In Marvel comics there has always been world destroying and world shattering events which effect the world in very tragic ways. But has there ever been a mention of the economic effects of these events? Has it ever been mentioned that world market or economy has shattered due to a particular event?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Marvel Earth-616 universe suffered the same sub-prime mortgage crisis (and global downturn) as our own world.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Marvel Comics Presents #7 - Market Correction](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/marvel-comics-presents-7/4000-714666/)</sup></sub>

Comment: has there been a mention of the economic crisis due to the events or works done by the superheroes